# Set double as a Label in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a shopping cart. I have a GridView with all of my products and I have an update button which, when clicked, I want to take the values in the price column and multiply it with the input values in the quantity TextBox and display it in the ItemTotal Label. My SQL inputs for lblPrice is in decimal form and however it is displayed on the gridview as $_.00. I keep running into a Format Exception for lblPrice. I was wondering if there is a way for me to convert lblPrice back to a decimal but still have it displayed as a price on the gridview?

ShoppingCart.aspx

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer"
        ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" ErrorMessage="Value must be a whole number" ForeColor="Red" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

ShoppingCart.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvProductsList.Rows)
    {
        double lblPrice = Convert.ToDouble(((Label)row.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label).Text);//convert value of lbl to double
        int txtQuantity = int.Parse(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox).Text);//convert value of textbox to int
        Label lblItemTotal = (row.FindControl("lblItemTotal")) as Label;//find lblItemTotal label in each row
        lblItemTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(lblPrice * txtQuantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're going down the right path. What isn't working?

Comment: I get a System.FormatException stating that the "Input string was not in a correct format." for the  double lblPrice = Convert.ToDouble(((Label)row.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label).Text);

Comment: What is an example value for that label, `lblPrice`?

Comment: you should run in debug mode then check the text in `lblPrice` (mouse over or use `shift+F9` and paste `((Label)row.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label).Text` and press `revaluation`

Comment: On the SQL it is set as a decimal and an example is 3, but I formatted it as $3.00 on the gridview.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like your problem is that the string value "$3.00" cannot be converted to a double. That would make sense, because the dollar sign is not a valid number.

Comment: Is there a way to convert it back to a decimal but still have it displayed as $3.00 on the gridview?

Comment: There is. Give me a few minutes to write up an answer. In the meanwhile, you should update your question detailing the actual problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments, we discovered that the problem was this line:

```
double lblPrice = Convert.ToDouble(((Label)row.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label).Text);
```

The value of the label was something like $3.00. The conversion to a double was failing. This is because the string contains a dollar sign, which isn't a valid number.

What you can do is convert this back into a decimal via the [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb(v=vs.110).aspx) method, passing in the appropriate [NumberStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) - in this case, Currency.

```
Label lblPrice = (Label)row.FindControl("lblPrice");
decimal price = decimal.Parse(lblPrice.Text, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

You may want to look into [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, for better error handling.

Make sure to include the Globalization namespace in order to use NumberStyles.

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an error saying NumberStyles does not exist in this current context

Comment: @Jamie then add namespace [`System.Globalization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) to your .cs file : `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: Thank you, Pham. Yes, make sure to add the Globalization namespace. I have updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I now have an error for the line 

lblItemTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(lblPrice * txtQuantity);

"Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' and 'int'"

Do you know how to adjust it so it can do the multiplication?

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sure there is a solution for that as well. On StackOverflow, it is preferred to only have one question at a time. Try to figure out the problem on your own for a bit and if you still have a problem, feel free to write up another question and someone will probably be able to help you out.

Comment: Be sure to also mark answers as accepted if they solved your problem described in the question! This helps future visitors that have similar problems.

Comment: @Jamie you **should not** name your `double lblPrice` exactly as the name of control label price. You should name it `double price` or something else. Same as `int quantity`. And aware more about **naming convention** please

Comment: @j.f. sorry, but i think my comment is very clearly about the error of that `Label` type. And how could I know what OP did? It's all in the code he show in question, you see.

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed my problem!